# How to avoid SQLException TimeOut error in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a really easy SQL stored procedure and with that I try to find an item and try to delete that item from the list but when I execute this stored procedure generally I got Timeout response...

The datalist where I try to delete item, has 4553 rows but I got Timeout error.

Why?

Here my stored procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[LimitRemove]
@Id int 
as

if EXISTS (select * from FraudDet with(NOLOCK) where CfdCfeId = @Id)
   begin
         delete from FraudDet where CfdCfeId = @Id
   end
```

Comment: Definitely not with `NOLOCK`. That means `read dirty and duplicate data while taking even more locks`. Somehow, some other query, perhaps one with `NOLOCK`, has taken excessive locks on that table and prevents the `DELETE` statement from completing.

Comment: Check the Activity Monitor in SSMS to see which connection is blocking your own and inspect its query. Perhaps it's a big SELECT? Or a client application has started a long-running transaction and forgot to close it? Perhaps *your own* code read a lot of data from that table inside a transaction? Each of these would block modification operations from other connections

Comment: BTW that `EXISTS` is pointless as `DELETE` performs the *same* check. The query in `EXISTS` forces the same search to run *twice*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so you mean i will just use delete function??

Comment: The DELETE *statement* already contains a `WHERE` clause that will search for the records to delete. If no records match, nothing will be deleted. There's no need to check twice

Comment: 43K rows is no data at all though. SQL Server is used in multi-TB databases with billions of rows. To get timeouts with so little data there's a serious bug - something is blocking rows for far longer than needed. Perhaps it's the application itself?  A forgotten SSMS window with a `select * from FraudDet` query? Some other operation that started a transaction and forgot to commit it? Obviously you already hit that bug but tried to cover it up with `NOLOCK`

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). It's not a  "magic, pixie-dust turbo button."

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually DB server is in another country and this is my customer issue so i will delete NOLOCK but i'm don't thing so they have forgotten SSMS window

Comment: This means the applications that use the database have a problem. Again, use SSMS to find the blocking connections. Or use Extended events to capture blocking queries. All supported versions (ie SQL Server 2016 and later) have Query Store which can be used to find blocking queries

Comment: This isn't a single-statement issue.

Comment: [This short article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/when-nolock-locks) and accompanying video explain why NOLOCK doesn't help and the type of locks it produces. [Using NOLOCK? Here’s How You’ll Get the Wrong Query Results.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/using-nolock-heres-how-youll-get-the-wrong-query-results/) goes into more details.

Comment: If blocking is caused by big selects, or long transactions with SELECT queries, one way to handle it is to use [Snapshot isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server).With snapshot isolation, SELECTs no longer block modifications, although modifications still block each other

Comment: Do you have an index (or primary key/unique constraint) on `CfdCfeId`? Without one, a full scan is required and may lead to blocking and timeouts.

Comment: Are there any triggers on `FraudDet`? Is there an `on delete cascade` constraint on the table?

Comment: Does the DELETE run fine outside of the Stored Procedure? If so, you could be running into a parameter sniffing issue. To get around this, you could create a new variable inside the stored procedure and set its value to `@Id` (e.g., `DECLARE @DeleteId INT = @Id;`) and then use the new variable in lieu of @Id (e.g., `delete from FraudDet where CfdCfeId = @DeleteId;`).